# NoSuchDriverException error trying to use selenium for Microsoft Edge

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, microsoft-edge

I am trying to scrape data using Selenium with Microsoft edge but I keep getting this error message.

```
PS C:\Users\Queensley\Desktop\hustle> python
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Edge()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Queensley\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\Users\Queensley\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 94, in driver_location
    output = self.run(args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Queensley\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 140, in run
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}.\n{result}{stderr}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: C:\Users\Queensley\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser MicrosoftEdge --output json.
{'code': 65, 'message': 'error sending request for url (https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/LATEST_RELEASE_119_WINDOWS): error trying to connect: dns error: No such host is known. (os error 11001)', 'driver_path': '', 'browser_path': ''}
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Queensley\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Queensley\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Queensley\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for MicrosoftEdge using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

To scrape data from webpages with selenium on Microsoft edge.

Answer (score 1):

Does your current EdgeDriver match the version of MS Edge? If possible, please provide a code sample that reproduces the issue. I did a simple test and it works fine. Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace tells you to visit https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location to know more about the `NoSuchDriverException` you're experiencing.

In order to drive Microsoft Edge, Selenium needs to send commands to it via an executable driver. This error means the necessary driver could not be found by any of the means Selenium attempts to use.

To fix this, you have many options. You can either use the latest version of Selenium, use the PATH environment variable or download the driver for edge. I would encourage you to visit the link and skim through the solutions suggested there. Be sure to choose Python since that's the language you're using and Windows since it appears you're using that.